# JAAS Custom Login Module with Wildfly

Tags: servlets, ejb, wildfly, jaas, user-roles

I'm trying to develop a custom JAAS login module, which consumes a token and get's the user data from different sources.
It should work as an authentication realm for wildfly 8.2.1 final. I've got a test servlet in which I want to authenticate so the allowed roles for a injected EJB is checked.

The test from this site: http://www.radcortez.com/custom-principal-and-loginmodule-for-wildfly/ In fact I even started with his git project.

Because I only use a token, I can not use `request.login(username, password)` to initiate the wildfly login process. So I tried this:

```
@Inject
private SampleEJB sampleEJB;

...

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = request.getParameter("token");
    try{
        context = new LoginContext("TokenLoginDomain", new TokenCallbackHandler(token));
        context.login();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.getWriter().println("username=" + exampleEJB.getPrincipalName());
}
```

My EJB looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class SampleEJB {
    @Resource
    private EJBContext ejbContext;

    @RolesAllowed("partner")
    public String getPrincipalName() {
        return ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

How do I start the login process without credentials in a servlet, so the user is logged in as wildfly user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't authenticate that way in Java EE. With the given code you'll only be authenticated within the `LoginContext` instance.

As you already found out `request.login(username, password)` triggers the authentication process, but it's limited to the username/password credential.

In this case you should not only write a custom LoginModule (identity store), but a custom authentication mechanism as well. Authentication mechanisms are the controllers so to speak in the authentication process, while the identity store is the model.

Custom authentication mechanisms can be added via the JASPIC SPI, which WildFly supports well.

You can register a `ServerAuthModule` (SAM) from the app with some utility code that you can copy from here: https://github.com/arjantijms/glassfish-sam-ee-namespaces/tree/master/src/main/java/javax/security/authenticationmechanism

Then actually register the SAM with code as shown here:

https://github.com/arjantijms/glassfish-sam-ee-namespaces/blob/master/src/main/java/test/SamAutoRegistrationListener.java

Comment: Thank you Arjan! After visiting your weblog it is still not clear for me,  which classes do I have to implement? Is it only the `javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule` and configuring wildfly or do I have to write more code?

Comment: You only implement `ServerAuthModule`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok, I took your git repo and started to play with it. I changed the servlet trying to use `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()` and `request.isUserInRole("partner")`, which is working.  But trying to access a EJB annotated with `@RolesAllowed("partner")` is not working. I get an Invalid User Exception (JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed ...) Do I still miss something?

Comment: >`Do I still miss something?` - Your code is likely correct, but WildFly 8.2.1 contains a bug that causes this to fail. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4625 It's fixed in WildFly 9, so upgrading to that or to WildFly 10 should fix it.

Comment: It starts working in WildFly 9. Just startet with your repo and changed the `ServerAuthModule`. If someone else stumbles upon this topic, don't forget to add the security domain, explained here: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/08/activating-jaspic-in-jboss-wildfly.html

Comment: Does `javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule` support Dependency Injection?  Can I inject EJB or other CDI `@ApplicationScoped` beans in it?  How do I get the SAM to talk with my LoginModule?

Comment: @EricB. You can't inject, but you can request things via JNDI or CDI.current(). For talking to the specific case of the LoginModule there's the JASPIC Bridge Profile. For the "server installed" username/password identity store there's the PasswordValidationCallback.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Thanks; that's actually what threw me into a quandry.  I was leveraging the java:comp/BeanManager to perform programatic injection, but apparently it isn't available in all types of threads.  For instance, when I had my LoginModule that was being triggered by a Remote EJB auth process, WF threw exceptions that the BeanManager could not be found.  I found it challenging making my dependencies available in the LoginManager and was wondering if there was a better way.